# Convert constant Double to Int in llvm IR

Tags: llvm

Given the following IR,

```
%1 = call double @llvm.pow.f64(double %conv, double 9.000000e+00)
```

when the fraction part of second argument is zero, I want to get it(second argument) in int type.

Can someone please suggest a method for this conversion?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are conversion instructions for this:

[fptoui](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#i_fptoui)

[fptosi](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#i_fptosi)

**EDIT:**

If you wish to convert `llvm::ConstantFP`, you can call `getValueAPF()` method, which would return you `llvm::APFloat`. See [documentation](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1APFloat.html#pub-methods) on how to convert `llvm::APFloat` to integer.

Comment: I want to convert value at compile time, I don't want to add an extra instruction to the IR.

Comment: I think, it would be optimized anyway, but, sure, you can do it manually. See updated answer.