# Does nvcc have an equivalent of fsingle-precision-constant?

Tags: cuda

gcc allows [-fsingle-precision-constant](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html) to save the trouble of manually adding f to every literal constant. Is there any convenient equivalent in nvcc?

Comment: nvcc manual is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#introduction).

Comment: already read the manual before posting the question here at SO. I would expect some undocumented compiler options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is no for newer architectures (or at least not with the compiler driver or device C compiler)

The old Open64 based compiler supported an enormous range of command line options (although many didn't do anything). It was probably possible to pass `-Xcompiler=-fshort-double` to force all double precision calculations into single precision. The compiler used to do this automagically for double precision floating point when compiling to sm_10, sm_11 and sm_12 targets which lacked native double precision support. The old compiler is still used for compute 1.x targets, so this is still possible.

The new cicc LVVM front end (which is used for devices > 1.x compute capability) supports a much, much shorter list of arguments, and they are not documented AFAIK. My own poking around shows the following options for controlling code generation and output:

```
-generate-line-info
-device-c
-kernel-params-are-restrict
-restrict
-disable-inlining
-Wno-memory-space
-disable-llc-opts
-show-src
-g
-O3
-O0
-fmad=0
-fmad=1
-prec-div=0
-prec-div=1
-prec-sqrt=0
-prec-sqrt=1
-ftz=0
-ftz=1
-m64
-m32
```

So I think you are out of luck. However, if you *really* want to do this, there is probably scope to write an LLVM pass yourself which transforms double precision constants to floats in the cicc emitted IR. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9288549/681865) looks like someone asking about more or less the same thing, and might give you a place to start.